# Blank white background loop

Tags: jquery

I use a loop to change the background images multiple times. After the fourth image there is a blank white background. Could someone see why is it so?

```
var images = ['img/icecream-993678_1280.png', 'img/little-cake-1426070_1920.png', "img/sweet-1104378_1280.jpg", "img/gummibarchen-1506173_1920.jpg"];
var count=0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){ 
         nFunct(images);
        });
         });

function nFunct(images) {
     var bg = images[count];
     $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
     count = count + 1;
     if (count > images.length) {
     count = 0;

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change the `if` statement at the end to `if (count > images.length - 1)`. Length is not zero-based, so `images.length` is 4. However, the index of the last image is 3, so after the last image displays `count` increments to 4, but since 4 is not greater than 4, so the loop runs one more time. Once the count gets to 5, *then* the if statement passes and `count` is reset to 0.

Using `(count >= images.length)` works as well.

Comment: or `if (count === images.length)`